# How to add row series per unique column value pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row-number

I would like to number the rows in in my data frame (and add this as a column) where the counting starts at 1 again for every distinct **Number**. I have tried using `df['Row number'] = np.arange(len(df))` but this gives a continuous numbering of the rows.

Example of the data frame I have:

```
Number Value
1234   a
1234   b
1234   x
5678   t
5678   y
5678   p
```

Example of the data frame I want:

```
Number Value   Row number
1234   a       1
1234   b       2
1234   x       3
5678   t       1
5678   y       2
5678   p       3
```

Anyone knows how I can do this or what function I should use? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `groupby` and `cumcount()`, with a `+1` as the default would be to start from `0`:

```
df['Row number'] = df.groupby('Number').cumcount() + 1

print(df)

   Number Value  Row number
0    1234     a           1
1    1234     b           2
2    1234     x           3
3    5678     t           1
4    5678     y           2
5    5678     p           3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed exactly what I needed